Moving SplineAnimate Objects Over Time With Proportional Speed
What I'm doing
I'm using Unity's Spline package and I'm trying to move SplineAnimate objects across a Spline, similar to a racing game's mini-map UI.
public class TurnGaugeIcon
{
     public SplineAnimate SplineAnimate;
     public float CurrentSpeed;
     public float startingPoint;
     public float distanceToMove;
     public float remainingTravelDistance;
     public float remainingTravelTime;
}


When I Play() the SplineAnimate objects, I want the icons to move faster than one another based on their current speed, and then all Pause() when one reaches the end of the Spline.
I want this process to always take the same amount of time to complete. I'm using the float variable _splineTravelTime to store the desired time I want it to take.
So, in the example below, let's say we know Mario will reach the end of the Spline first. If _splineTravelTime is .5, then regardless of where Mario starts on the Spline, I want him to reach the end in .5 seconds.


How I'm doing it
First, I figure out which icon will reach the end of the Spline first based on their starting point and their speed:
private void GetIconStats()
{
    // Get the racing data for all of the icons
    foreach (TurnGaugeIcon icon in _activeTurnGaugeIcons)
    {
        // Where the icon starts on the Spline
        icon.startingPoint = icon.SplineAnimate.NormalizedTime;
        
        // How much farther it needs to travel to reach the end of the Spline
        icon.remainingTravelDistance = (1 - icon.startingPoint);
        
        // The time it will take to travel the remaining distance
        icon.remainingTravelTime = icon.remainingTravelDistance / icon.CurrentSpeed;
    }
}

_nextWinningIcon is the icon with the lowest remainingTravelTime and will reach the end of the Spline first.
private void GetRacePredictions()
{
    // Sort the list of Turn Gauge icons by ascending remaining travel time
    _activeTurnGaugeIcons.Sort((unit1, unit2) => unit1.remainingTravelTime.CompareTo(unit2.remainingTravelTime));

    // The sorted list's first element is the icon predicted to win
    _nextWinningIcon = _activeTurnGaugeIcons[0];
}

I think my approach is correct up until this point.

This is likely where my logic falls apart:
To my knowledge, SplineAnimate doesn't have a function that says "Make the remaining journey take X seconds".
The only variable that seems usable is SplineAnimate.Duration, which is the time it takes to complete the entire journey from 0 - 1. Working with this, I tried setting the Duration to match what I need.
For example: If an icon is .75/100 of the Spline journey, and I need the remaining .25 to take .5 seconds, I would make the Duration 2 seconds.
(Desired Time (.5 seconds) / Remaining distance (.25/100) = 2
private void SetTheSplineAnimateDuration()
{
    // Keep track of the icons normalizedTime (their position on the Spline)
    // This is because once the Duration is changed, the icon's position on the Spline will change
    var normalizedTime = _nextWinningIcon.SplineAnimate.NormalizedTime;
    
    // Set the icon that will reach the end first's Duration (_splineTravelTime is the desired uniform time)
    _nextWinningIcon.SplineAnimate.Duration = _splineTravelTime / _nextWinningIcon.remainingTravelDistance;
    
    // Move the icon back to their correct position on the Spline
    _nextWinningIcon.SplineAnimate.NormalizedTime = normalizedTime;
    
    // Next, set the remaining icons duration proportionally
    // 'i' is 1 because the winning icon is 0
    for (int i = 1; i < _activeTurnGaugeIcons.Count; i++)
    {
        // How much the icon should move
        _activeTurnGaugeIcons[i].distanceToMove = (_activeTurnGaugeIcons[i].AssignedUnit.CurrentSpeed * _nextWinningIcon.remainingTravelTime) + _activeTurnGaugeIcons[i].startingPoint;

        // Keep track of the icons normalizedTime (their position on the Spline)
        // This is because once the Duration is changed, the icon's position on the Spline will change
        normalizedTime = _activeTurnGaugeIcons[i].SplineAnimate.NormalizedTime;
        _activeTurnGaugeIcons[i].SplineAnimate.Duration = _splineTravelTime / _activeTurnGaugeIcons[i].distanceToMove;

        // Move the icon back to the proper starting point
        _activeTurnGaugeIcons[i].SplineAnimate.NormalizedTime = normalizedTime;
    }
    
}


Lastly, I wait for an icon to reach the end of the Spline.
When it does, I move it back to start and pause all icons.
    private IEnumerator PlayTheIcons()
{
    // Bool to stay in loop
    bool turnGaugeIsUpdating = true;
    
    // Move all of the icons
    foreach (TurnGaugeIcon icon in _activeTurnGaugeIcons)
    {
        icon.SplineAnimate.Play();
    }

    // If an icon reaches the end of the Spline, break from the loop.
    while (turnGaugeIsUpdating)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < _activeTurnGaugeIcons.Count; i++)
        {
            if (_activeTurnGaugeIcons[i].SplineAnimate.NormalizedTime >= 1)
            {
                turnGaugeIsUpdating = false;
            }
        }

        yield return null;
    }

    // An icon has reached the end, so move it back to start and pause all icons
    foreach (TurnGaugeIcon icon in _activeTurnGaugeIcons)
    {
        icon.SplineAnimate.Pause();
    }

    _nextWinningIcon.SplineAnimate.NormalizedTime = 0;
}

This only seems to work the way I want it to one time. The first time I call Play(), the fastest icon reaches the end of the Spline in .5 seconds, and all the other icons move proportionally based on their CurrentSpeed stat.
The second Time I Play() the icons, the second icon to reach the end of the Spline also correctly goes from it's current position to the end in .5 seconds, but the other icons gain an insane speed boost and move way too fast. After 3-4 iterations of moving the icons, multiple icons reach the end at the same time, which should never happen unless the icons' remainingTravelTime has the same value (they don't). This completely breaks it altogether.

Put simply, I want icons with higher CurrentSpeed to move faster, but I also want the icon that is destined to reach the end first, to take the amount of time I set in _splineTravelTime(.5 seconds).
I'm also not confident about using so many float values because I want this to be consistent. I don't know an alternative since SplineAnimate.NormalizedTime takes a float value from 0-1 to plot the SplineAnimate object on the Spline.
I must be messing up the math somewhere in my SetTheSplineAnimateDuration() method.
Any assistance would be immensely appreciated!
Thank you so much for taking the time!
